# Programa em C multiplataforma

Tags: c, linux, windows, unix

Se eu fazer um programa em C e não usar nenhuma biblioteca do Windows deixando o programa totalmente puro em C eu posso compilar ele para Linux também?

e funcionará normalmente?

Answer (score 1):

Sim, se for usado o padrão ANSI C, ou bibliotecas compatíveis, então será possível compilar para windows e linux.

Comment: Existe bibliotecas gráficas do C pelo padrão ANSI?

Comment: Existe o **Qt** que pode ser construir para muitas plataformas dá uma olhada nele.

Dá uma olhada no **GTK** também.

Comment: Eu não sei se o Qt é *cross compiler*, eu creio que o fonte deverá ser compilado sobre a plataforma destino.

Comment: Sim, até aí tudo bem. Sem precisar fazer drásticas alterações no código(sem reprogramar duas vezes para cada plataforma)

Comment: Qt é C++, é praticamente impossível usar com C, embora tecnicamente exista como, com muito trabalho, vai ficar porco. GTK para Windows por conta e risco. Algumas coisas são bem específicas e nenhuma biblioteca consegue abstrair. A Qt até consegue resultado bom nas diversas plataformas, outras bibliotecas tem resultados variados.

Comment: Boa observação @bigown.

Comment: Na verdade até no próprio Java não existe tal compatibilidade de ambientes, estou em um projeto desktop, estava desenvolvendo no linux, e a maioria dos clientes eram **Window** e vez por outra bugs relacionados a eventos aparaciam.